# Get a row from a datatable in C# Visualstudio and then store the row in a datarow

Tags: c#, datarow

I have a dataset in c# visual studio. I have one of column values of the one of the rows. I need to select that row using that value and store it in a datarow so that I can delete it. So how can I get the row of the datatable from one of the column values. I was trying something like this:

```
DataRow rowtobeselected = TableName["SerialNumber = 156"];
```

But as you know this is wrong. Also I need to get another colum value
from this row. For eg I need to get the value from the column date.

```
string Date = rowtobeselected.date;
```

I want to do something like this. So how to do it correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTables support a SQL like Select syntax:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=net-5.0

```
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)OtherTable.SelectedItem; 
        string serialnumbr = row.Row["SerialNumber"].ToString();        
        DataRow[] result = TableName.Select("SerialNumber =" + serialNumbr);

        DataRow dr = result.FirstOrDefault();

        if (dr != null)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dr["Date"].ToString());
        }
```

Comment: I dont understand the problem, can you edit your post to explain

Comment: Thank you, but now I have a new problem. So I will tell you how this works. The the thing is this serial number I get from another Table which we select. This is how I get it                                                 DataRowView row = (DataRowView)OtherTable.SelectedItem;                                                    string serialnumbr = row.Row["SerialNumber"].tostring();                                                     now this serial number we use in DataRow[] result = tableName.Select("SerialNumber = serialnumbr"). rest in next comment as this one is already too long

Comment: But it is showing an error that the column serialnumbr cannot be found. But I tried printing out serialnumbr in a messagebox and it shows the value 149. Now I changed the program to DataRow[] result = tableName.Select("SerialNumber = 149") and this also works. But when I use the string variable serialnumbr instead of 149, it gives me an error. What can be the reason for this. Thank you.

Comment: Your filter there is a string literal. Its looking for a non existent row where the column SerialNumber = the literal string value searialnumbr